# Difference between UIView.init and without init in swift 3

Tags: swift, uiview

I am programmatically adding two UIView. As shown below example:-

```
 let firstview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height-63,width:self.view.frame.width, height: 80))
 let secondview = UIView.init(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height-63,width:self.view.frame.width, height: 80) )
```

Both are work perfectly.

> What is the difference between both of these UIViews?

Comment: Both are same ,

Comment: @MikeAlter before Swift 3.0 we are using without UIView.init() In Swift 3.0 or later what is the need to add .init()?

Comment: In both case it will call constructor so you don't need to panic , it will work fine for you either init or without init

Comment: @MikeAlter will you please give me a valid revision behind that particular change

Comment: There is *no* change.  You don't typically use `.init` here, before Swift 3.0 or after Swift 3.0.

Comment: I don't remember about previous versions . as well as  even I don't aware about the actual reason behind it. As swift 3 comes with very major changes so it might be one of them

Comment: There was no change in Swift 3 and it was never needed to add `.init`.

Comment: Thanks to aware me for .init

Comment: @vadian There is one more question from my side is, How ( ) Brackets are been added to create object as I have seen any of class in  which init method  are  added they are accessible with () even though there is init() Method. but not () implementation

Comment: @MikeAlter putting brackets behind a class name is just a shorthand notation for writing `Class.init()`. It is just syntactic sugar, there is no magic behind it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are the same and call the same init function of `UIView`. It is best practice to not directly call the `init` though and just use `UIView(frame:)`

Comment: Thanks, Hodson sir.

Answer (score 5):

Writing empty parentheses after a class name ( `MyClass()` ) in `Swift` is equivalent to calling its initializer by writing `MyClass.init()`.

The same works for initializers accepting input arguments, so the two lines in your question are equivalent.